# Google Map does not detect bounds changed upon resize dynamically

Tags: ajax, google-maps-api-3

I have an AJAX map query function that is triggered whenever the page loads or the map (500x500px) is dragged or zoomed:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {

 var bounds = map.getBounds();
 // do something

});
```

I also have a button that triggers a resize of this map to the extent of the browser window. Upon clicking, I realise that the **map bounds** remains as 500x500px even though the map stretches across the entire window, causing the map tiles to be incompletely loaded.

Here is the partial code for the resizing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('button').click(function() {
  $('#map').css({'height': new_height, 'width': new_width});
 }
});
```

Dragging the map around doesn't solve the problem. Google Map detects the new map bounds only when I click on the maximise/restore button of the browser. How to go around solving this problem without the manual effort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $('#map').css({'height': new_height, 'width': new_width});
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });
});
```